# UWP: Unable to force user consent dialog to appear. webTokenRequest.Properties.Add("prompt", "consent") not working

Tags: asp.net, uwp, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I can’t seem to be able to force the user consent dialog to appear.
The first time user logs in, the consent dialog properly comes up.
However, after we change the app permissions or the user manually removes the app consent (from portal.office.com/myapps) then we can no longer cause the consent dialog to re appear.

Details:

- UWP Windows 10 native client connecting to WebApp (ASP.NET) which calls downstream WebApi (O365) using the “on-behalf” oath2 pattern (using latest 3+ ADAL libraries)
- Single tenant WebApp (no special admin perms)
- After changing WebApp permissions (eg adding more o365 apis) or the user removing the WebApp consent, the WebApp’s AcquireToken returns AADSTS65001
- Using wtr.Properties.add(“prompt”, “consent”) in the UWP client app does not cause consent dialog to re-appear
- Re-cycling WebApp (to clear the built-in AAD token cache – it doesn’t use its own token cache) or clearing the client’s token cache (by login out) does not help

What is the proper way to having the user re-consent?

Comment: Can you confirm that the querystring "&prompt=consent" is being put into your login url? Can you share the link that is being generated?